# Shiny - Position wellPanels Vertically

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to position well panels along the left side of a plot that is also in a well panel.  However, the code I have now produces a page as pictured below.

[image: Page Screenshot]

I know adding an offset next to the column command (ex: column(2, offset = 2, ...)) is a horizontal positioning of the wellPanel, but I need to change the wellPanel's position vertically so there isn't that white space gap on the page.  My sample code is below.

```
#Check packages to use in library
{
  library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used
  library('magrittr')
  library('dplyr')
}

#Data

ID_no <- 123
Data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
employee_name <- as.character("Employee1")
date <- Sys.Date()
ID_1 <-data.frame(ID_no, Data_val, employee_name, date)

ID_no <- 456
Data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
employee_name <- as.character("Employee2")
date <- Sys.Date()-10
ID_2 <-data.frame(ID_no, Data_val, employee_name, date)

data <-rbind(ID_1, ID_2)
IDchoices <- as.character(unique(data$ID_no))

# UI

ui <- fluidPage(
 fluidRow(
    column(2,
           wellPanel(
             selectInput(inputId = "ID", label="Select ID:", choices = IDchoices, selected = "1", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)
          )),
   column(10,
          wellPanel(plotOutput("plot1")
          )),
   column(2,
           wellPanel(
             span(h5(strong("Employee:")), h5(textOutput("Staff_name"))),
            span(h5(strong("Date:")),h5(textOutput("Date"))))
   )
 )
)

#SERVER

server <- function(input, output, session)
{

}

#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Shiny has 12 columns per `fluidRow()`. You used (2+10+2=)14 columns, so this is why your page looks like this. I am not sure, if I understand you correctly, but if you want that some boxes are fixed on the left side, you could use a `sidebarLayout`? http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    column(2,
           fluidRow(
             wellPanel(
               selectInput(inputId = "ID", label="Select ID:", choices = IDchoices, selected = "1", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)               
             )
           ),
           fluidRow(
             wellPanel(
               span(h5(strong("Employee:")), h5(textOutput("Staff_name"))),
               span(h5(strong("Date:")),h5(textOutput("Date"))))
           )
    ),
    column(10,
           wellPanel(plotOutput("plot1")
           ))
)

#SERVER

server <- function(input, output, session)
{

}

#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Yes I am, thank you! For some reason I thought that each wellPanel had to be listed in a separate column (which is why I duplicated the 2 there).  That makes a lot of sense now that I am seeing it.

Comment: are you still looking for an improv. (concern. upvote) or is it finished for you?

Comment: No your suggestion was what I was looking for.

Comment: then i would appreciate an upvote :) (the grey "up" arrow)